Apache Camel's DefaultErrorHandler: Sending data from a 'to' endpoint in one container to another endpoint in a different container
I'm trying to send information to an endpoint in a microservice within a container from a Camel service also in a container, but I'm encountering this error that I don't know how to solve.
 DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: B785993430958A9-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: B785993430958A9-0000000000000000). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:4545 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused

restConfiguration()
                .component("netty-http")
                .host("")
                .port(7575);

        rest("/card")
                .post("/saveCard")
                .consumes("application/json")
                .type(DataPayCardDTO.class)
                .to("direct:saveCard");

        from("direct:saveCard")
                .log("Received POST request: ${body}")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                .process(new CardProcessor())
                /* .unmarshal(new JacksonDataFormat(DataPayCardDTO.class)) */

                .log("processing message: ${body}")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
                .to("http://localhost:4545/card/CardSave?bridgeEndpoint=true");

If anyone knows how to solve this error, I would appreciate it

You don't show a route to listen on port 4545... is that in the same app? If it's in a different container you would need to expose the container port to local host port 4545.
